# How to know when a popup window closes

Tags: javascript

I have created a window like so:

```
var myWindow = window.open(...)
```

I'm wanting to know when this window closes back in the main code. Something that maybe I can do with the `myWindow` variable. I've tried using the unonload function such as:

```
myWindow.onunload = function () {...}
```

But this isn't being called at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are looking for ```myWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {...}```, however it may not work in all browsers

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding an event handler from the parent window for when the child closes, you could have the child call a function on the parent:

parent window

```
// needs to be somewhere global so the child window can call it
var onChildWindowClose = function () {
    // ...
};
```

child window

```
window.onunload = function () {
    if (opener && !opener.closed) {
        opener.onChildWindowClose();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really event handling, but you may try to monitor your window `closed` property with `setInterval` :

```
myWindow=window.open("","","width=200,height=300");

var timer = setInterval(
                    function(){
                      if(myWindow.closed){
                          clearInterval(timer);
                          alert('closed');
                       }
                     }, 1000);
```